# Tradução do carrinho woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tradução

A página do carrinho de compras no meu site wordpress está sem tradução. Nos arquivos po e mo, está tudo correto, a sincronização está feita, mas mesmo assim a página do carrinho não está traduzida.
Isso não acontece apenas em um dos meu domínios, acontece em vários. Um exemplo: www.nicolysemijoias.com.br
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Vá no arquivo .po e edite o texto de tradução, mesmo que esteja 100% igual, remova o texto atual e digite a tradução. Já aconteceu isso comigo, fiz isso e resolveu mas não me pergunte o por que. kkkkkkkk

Comment: Eu fiz isso também. Deu certo em um domínio, mas em nenhum outro está funcionando. Obrigado pela disposição :)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Gabriel!

Pode ser que existam dois arquivos de tradução para os seus sites, e que o de prioridade maior seja o que não está traduzido.

Para saber se existem dois arquivos, verifique os seguintes diretórios:

(podem estar no diretório geral de linguagens do Wordpress)
"wp-content/languages/plugins"

(ou no diretório do plugin Wocoomerce)
"wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages"

Caso existam dois, verifique se os dois estão com as traduções.

Se não houverem dois arquivos, outra possibilidade seria o .mo que está no site não ser a compilação do .po que possui a tradução. Para realizar esse teste, baixe um programa como o Poedit (https://poedit.net/download) abra o .po, depois vá em "Arquivo > Compilar para MO..." e faça o upload desse novo .mo para o site.

Espero ter ajudado. Se possível, gostaria de seu feedback sobre minhas dicas.

Abraços!